# error while executing bash script -> command not found

Tags: debian, bash, wget

i made this script here, and get the error

> IA-exporto.sh: 13: wget: not found

i tried changing the " by ` and mixed all together and rearranged, but it just won't do..

```
#!/bin/bash
UNAME="maximilian"
PWD="password"
DATE=`date +%Y\-%m\-%d`
DAY=`date +%d`
MONTH=`date +%m`
YEAR=`date +%Y`

PATH="/root/test/IA"

URL="http://www.my-corpo.com/_backend/index.php?date=$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY&view=csv"
COMMAND="wget --user=$UNAME --password=$PWD $URL -O $PATH-$DATE.csv"
$COMMAND
```

i even tryed to set before and after every variable a ", so it looks like

```
COMMAND="wget --user="$UNAME" --password="$PWD" "$URL" -O "$PATH"-"$DATE".csv"
```

but when i  **echo $COMMAND** it looks very right, in fact, when i copy it from and insert it, it works..

Comment: are you running the script via cron?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overriding the `$PATH` variable, which determines which directories are searched for executables (like `wget`):

```
PATH="/root/test/IA"
```

So the shell is only looking in `/root/test/IA` for the `wget` command. Change your variable name to something else.

Comment: Holy noodlemonster, you finished my workday after 10 hours. Thank you very much!

Comment: Besides PATH, there are a number of other all-caps variables with special meanings. Using lowercase (or mixed-case) variable names is a good way to avoid problems like this. Also, storing commands in variables before running them can cause a variety of problems -- see [BashFAQ #050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 2):

Generally it is considered good practice to use **full paths** in scripts to not depend on preset search paths.

1. `which wget` will tell you the path to wget (probably `/usr/bin/wget`)
2. you change `COMMAND="wget --user...."` to `COMMAND="/usr/bin/wget --user...."` (or wherever your wget sits)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do:

```
    PATH=/root/test/IA:$PATH
```

instead of

```
    PATH=/root/test/IA
```

In order to preserve your current PATH variable but give the executables in /root/test/IA preference over other similarly named executables in the current PATH.

It is generally considered **bad practice to use full paths** to executables (i.e. to not use the PATH concept) in scripts, because this destroys the portability of the scripts and more importantly, it prevents you from overriding distribution default executables with your own. For example, most distros install wget in /usr/bin. If you want to install another version of wget in /usr/local/bin or in ~/.bin, without removing the distro default wget, but use your own wget in the script, then you should set PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH. This use of PATH is a critical feature if you do cross-platform development. In this situation you might have five different gcc toolchains installed. You don't want to have to have five different versions of a compilation script, so you rely on the shell's use of PATH to select the correct toolset.

Note that if you intend to run this script from crontab, you might have to explicitly add directories to the PATH variable because the default cron PATH includes just a few directories, as [gregseth explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135478/how-to-simulate-the-environment-cron-executes-a-script-with).